# Can't run a topology in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm, topology

I'm using petrel 0.9.3 and apache storm with the same version. When I try to run a topology I'm getting the following error:

```
(petrel)[root@localhost example1]# petrel submit --config topology.yaml --logdir `pwd`
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/petrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/petrel-0.9.3.0.3-py2.7.egg/petrel/cmdline.py", line 111, in main
    func(**args.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/petrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/petrel-0.9.3.0.3-py2.7.egg/petrel/cmdline.py", line 32, in submit
    sourcejar = get_sourcejar()
  File "/usr/local/petrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/petrel-0.9.3.0.3-py2.7.egg/petrel/cmdline.py", line 23, in get_sourcejar
    storm_version = get_storm_version()
  File "/usr/local/petrel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/petrel-0.9.3.0.3-py2.7.egg/petrel/cmdline.py", line 17, in get_storm_version
    version = subprocess.check_output(['storm', 'version']).strip()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the storm bin location to $PATH